# Need help installing PHP5-DOM

Tags: php, yum, installation

I try to install PHP5-DOM on CentOS 6.5 using `yum install php-xml` and get this error:

```
Error: Package: php-xml-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
  Requires:  php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
  Installed: php-common-5.4.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
             php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.28-1.el6.remi
  Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
             php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
  Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
             php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
  You could try using --skip-broken to work round the problem
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How could I install it on php 5.4?

Answer (score 1):

You originally installed PHP from the remi repository, but you forgot to enable the repository when adding this package.

To fix the problem, re-enable the repository, either temporarily: `yum --enablerepo=remi install php-xml` or permanently by editing `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`.